# Merging in without losing any rows

Tags: r

I have 2 data set with id's and am trying to merge them with R, without losing any rows.

I am using the merge function

`merge(x,y,"id")`

I am not getting all the rows. I have less, why?

What is the correct function to do this operation?

Comment: Hi, maybe you want `dplyr::full_join()`.

Comment: Hi memile, please post a minimum reproducible example so it is easy for us here to cut and paste your code into our own R sessions, get at least a subset of your two data sets, and be able to reproduce your effort and confirm a solution. thanks :)

Comment: `merge(x = x, y = y, by = "id", all = TRUE)`  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right